# ¿Si hago una variable de objeto estatica TODAS las variables que contiene ese objeto se vuelven estaticas?

Tags: java, poo

Es decir si hago esta variable del objeto Perro, todas sus variables de clase (propiedades, como raza, color, nombreDelPerror) también se hacen estaticas junto con la variable de objeto "perro"?

```
class ejemplo{
    public static Perro perro;
 }
```

Mi pregunta se deriva, por que tengo una variable local en un método (Dentro de la clase Perro, que se supone que su tiempo de vida sólo dura mientras se ejecuta el metodo y finaliza su ejecución, y resulta que al volver a ejecutar ese método, el valor que le había puesto a esa variable se mantiene, y se supone que esto no devería ser. Ya que mi variable es sólo local, no es variable de clase y mucho menos es una variable estatica.

Llevo años programando y nunca me había pasado esto, ¿Qué sucede? Estoy confundido.

Mi unica teoría es que sea por que declaré "perro" como static, o por que esté programando con multiples hilos y cada hilo tiene un valor de esa variable.. no lo sé

Comment: Hasta dónde recuerdo, el compilador de java _brinca_ si intentas utilizar una variable local que no has inicializado, entonces, ¿cómo sabes que tiene el mismo valor que la vez anterior?

Comment: Por que a manera de test, hago un System.out.print("El valor de la variable es : " + variableLocal); y sigue con el mismo valor que le di cuando se ejecutó la primera vez el metodo, a pesar que desde la primera linea ya le di el valor de 0 (cero) y cuando entra a un if, vuelve a obtener el valor anterior de cuando entró a ese if, está muy extraño, se perfectamente como funciona el lifetime de las variables y el scope (alcance)

Comment: Definitivamente, los miembros de la clase no se hacen `static` y menos una variable local. Habría que ver el código de marras (un [mcve] idealmente), para ver si hay algo extraño con el código.